# using curses with raw_input in python

Tags: python, console-application, ncurses

In my python linux console application I use curses to handle displaying of data. At the same time I'd like to have an input line to enter commands, pretty much in good ol' irssi-style. With default curses getch() I'd have to do a lot of coding just to get the basic funcionality of raw_input function - arrow keys to move cursor / browse through the input history.

Is there a simple way to get such behavior working with curses, as it captures input events and I can't just use functions that read sys.stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curses.textpad

http://www.python.org/doc/2.4.1/lib/module-curses.textpad.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm now wondering, since textpad is limited in size to a window size, can I make it accept more text then the window size? Should I use pad instead of window?