# Receiving stdin input while other threads / processes are outputting

Tags: python, multithreading, ncurses, python-curses

I'm asking the same question as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539066/input-only-to-bottom-line-of-terminal), but in Python under Linux. I have a thread running in the background which output things constantly, but I would like to keep the input line at the bottom of the terminal without been flushed away. Can someone give me a code example? Suppose my code is like this:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def subproc():
  while True:
    print "something"
    sleep(1)
def main():
  p = Process(target=subproc)
  p.start()
  c = raw_input()
```

EDIT: by the way, I would like to keep the use of the `raw_input` function, if possible, because I want to have input history available.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there isn't any way of doing this that doesn't involve some serious or irritating consequences.

The way terminals scroll and handle stdin/stdout has not varied much in decades.

[Take a look at terminal escape sequences.](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) As long as the user terminal is based on the VT100 or ansi spec, these should work. You can use them to set the write location, clear lines, etc. But if a user scrolls, the illusion will break.

The problem of specifying a specific location on screen to output a character was addressed for early games like angband, rogue and nethack. The solution was the Curses library, [and there happens to be a curses python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

By using curses, you can achieve what your after. But I know of no way of doing this in standard standard shells

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was indeed asking for an example using the Python curses module. The post I linked to mentions the Curses library. I'm fine with the scrolling since it doesn't change the content being written and the new content to be written are written in the same way. It's just people need to scroll back to continue inputting. Resizing the window may be more problematic but I can first assume this does not happen. I just need a quick, working and possibly dirty solution. Also, one major concern I'm having is whether the raw_input function can still be used here.

Comment: @shaoyl85 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326922/using-curses-with-raw-input-in-python